# Adding program to the windows explorer context menu

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, registry, explorer

How do I add the program into context menu to receive the folder as argument while making the new item available when clicking on the folder background?

As of now I am trying to add the program to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell\MyProgram\command` and I do see the new menu item, however, if I try to add `%1` to receive the argument it is not working - I get an error.

As example:

`F:\Programs\program.exe` - Program starting correctly without receiving any arguments.

`"F:\Programs\program.exe"` `"%1"` - Error

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing
>   this action.

`"F:\Programs\program.exe %1"`- Error

> Application not found.

From what I have read the second option should be correct, but it is not working, why?

Comment: You need double quotes around everything. `"F:\Programs\program.exe" "%1"`

Comment: @KenWhite, I have them in the second case, they were missing for some reason, even thought I wrote them in the post in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter should be `%V`, not `%1`, as it seems `%V` returns a directory it was called from, while `%1` returns a file it was called from.